# AWS Babelfish co-releated sub query provides in correct results

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, babelfish

We are migrating a sql server Database to AWS Aurora Postgres with Babelfish enabled. I connected the Babelfish DB from SSMS through 1433 port. While I ran Babelfish compass report and fixed the un supported functionality. There are few issues which occurred as I was actually modifying the queries/SP's. One such issue is, there is a co-related sub query in an SP and when I created that SP in Babelfish, it was all good but when I execute the SP, it errors out with said error below. I tried replacing that with joins and tried using exists, CTE etc, I am unable to replicate the original results. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is the sample query. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

```
SELECT t.POLICY_DOCUMENT_ID,
        convert(xml, (select rd.Id as TagId, rd.def_id as RelatedDataDefId, rdd.name_tx as [Name], rd.VALUE_TX as TagCode, rdd.DATA_TYPE_CD as TagDataType, rdd.DOMAIN_CD as TagDomainName
                          from 
                                TEST_DATA rd 
                                join TEST_DATA_DEF rdd on rdd.relate_class_nm = 'PolicyDocument' and rd.def_id = rdd.id and rdd.ACTIVE_IN = 'Y'
                                --join #tempPDIDs th  on rd.relate_id = th.POLICY_DOCUMENT_ID 
                         where      rd.relate_id = t.POLICY_DOCUMENT_ID
                                for xml PATH('PolicyDocumentTag'), ROOT('PolicyDocumentTags'))) AS POLICY_DOCUMENT_TAGS_XML
        
        from
            #tempPDIDs t
            join TEST_DOCUMENT pd on pd.id = t.POLICY_DOCUMENT_ID and pd.PURGE_DT is null
            left join #tempPDIDFTSTX tmp on pd.id = tmp.POLICY_DOCUMENT_ID
```

Error:

```
Msg 33557097, Level 16, State 1, Line 72
missing FROM-clause entry for table "t"
```

Comment: `Msg 33557097` isn't an SQL Server error, it's a generic "I'm confused" error message thrown by Babelfish. It seems to get confused about aliases crossing subquery boundaries, see [\[Bug\]: SQL Error \[33557097\] \[S0001\]: missing FROM-clause entry for table "XX" #61](https://github.com/babelfish-for-postgresql/babelfish_extensions/issues/61)

Comment: Yeah, the same query works fine in Native MS Sql server.

Comment: I have rewritten the SP for a workaround, but that's lot of code, which I have added. The complexity is due to the converting the output to XML, which groups to a single table row consisting of all the XML documents.